# Simple code looping not working when method called via ASP.NET web method

Tags: asp.net, loops, asmx, webmethod

Any loops or iterations aren't working when I execute the code via a WebMethod. If I run the same code normally there is no problem. Basically, the top line of the for loop is executed then anything within the curly braces ignored. Any code below will be executed. I've tried with a foreach loop and the result is the same. This is very strange behavior and I have no idea what is causing it, any help is appreciated!

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyPageMethod()
{

  string str = string.Empty;

  string valueWillNotChange = string.Empty;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {

    str += i.ToString();

    // anything here or below will not get executed ...
    valueWillNotChange = str;

  }

}
```

Comment: Your question amounts to, "some fundamental piece of functionality of the operating system or programming language isn't working. I found a bug". The answer is always that there's a bug in your code, or you're not testing correctly. Millions of people have done loops in web services. If it was broken, they would have complained before now.

Comment: The variable fieldAndValue is only going to be available in the for loop. You are just assigning and not using it in the loop, so the way it is now, the loop really isn't doing anything. Is that your actual code you're using or just an example?

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public static void MyPageMethod()
    {
     
      string str = string.Empty;

      string valueWillNotChange = string.Empty;

      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        
        str += i.ToString();

        // anything here or below will not get executed ...
        valueWillNotChange = str;

      }

    }

Comment: Appreciate the swift response guys ...

@ John Saunders

I've done loops in web services myself before, that's why I'm confused by this sudden occurance - I'm a seasoned developer with over 10 years experience so I'm quite familiar with the programming basics.

Comment: @ moriartyn

I know the variable fieldAndValue is only available in the for loop, I'm happy with this. My point is that this line isn't being hit. To answer your question this wasn't the code I was using originally but I have tried just with this and this simple example won't work.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't explaining the problem but maybe the example below is a bit clearer. If I hit F5 and click the button the web form that triggers the WebMethod it hits okay, goes to the first line of the for loop, iterates that line 4 times, then exits. To test, I just created a new project, created a web form and copied the code and executed and it worked as expected.

Comment: I think there's an issue with the project (although god knows what - it's not that big and the web config hasn't had much added to it). I think I'll have to rebuild the solution unfortunately as this is happening on every page I try and test on.

Comment: Okay, edited the code sample above, might be a bit clearer now.

Comment: Did a simple copy and paste of the whole project, opened it and it works! Ran the existing project parallel just to check I wasn't missing something and it still didn't work - so identical projects running, one behaves correctly one doesn't. I guess you can close this but it'd be useful to know why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a stand alone unit test and validate it works at all.

As @John Saunders said, it's your code that doesn't work.

Comment: @ Chris Marisic

I suggest you read the comments before coming out with a pretty unhelpful "it's your code that doesn't work". I already did what you suggested and the code DID work (explained above), which is what is confusing. As I also said (please read), there's some issue with the project and I'll have to rebuild it.